ibapi (Python) - get data from the option Chain
I am starting to work with Python & the IBKR API and have a problem with receiving data from the option chain:
Within the option chain I am trying to find a strike based an a specific delta (or close to it).
So, let's say I want to find the strike price where delta ~ 0.20.
Additionally, I want to return the mid price of this strike (this is a future step, still struggling with the delta)
This is how I tried it so far, however I do not receive data back (process finished with exit code 0).
import threading
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import time


class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.nextOrderId = 0
        self.permId2ord = {}
        self.strike = 160

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print(f"Error: {reqId} {errorCode} {errorString}")

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        self.req_data(orderId)

    def req_data(self, orderId):
        optcontract = Contract()
        optcontract.symbol = "AAPL"
        optcontract.secType = "OPT"
        optcontract.exchange = "SMART"
        optcontract.currency = "USD"
        optcontract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "20240419"
        optcontract.strike = self.strike
        optcontract.right = "P"

        self.reqMarketDataType(4)
        self.reqMktData(orderId, optcontract, '106', False, False, [])

    def tickOptionComputation(self, reqId: int, tickType: int, impliedVol,
                              delta, optPrice, pvDividend,
                              gamma, vega, theta, undPrice):
        print(f"Delta: {delta} for option with reqId {reqId}")
        if delta > 0.22:
            self.strike -= 5
            self.req_data(reqId + 1)
        elif delta < 0.18:
            self.strike += 5
            self.req_data(reqId + 1)
        else:
            print(f"Found an option with Delta in the desired range. Strike: {self.strike} Delta: {delta}")
            self.cancelMktData(reqId)


def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 0)
    app.nextOrderId = 0
    # Call an initial request for OrderId increments
    app.reqIds(-1)
    # Initialize the run loop
    api_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: app.run(), daemon=True)
    api_thread.start()

    time.sleep(10)
    app.disconnect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Which TWS API version and TWS/ IB Gateway version are you using?

You miss some important contract details when you use reqMktData() function. Otherwise, you will get Error:  101   321   Error validating request.-'bP' : cause - When the local symbol field is empty, please fill the following fields (right, strike, expiry).     Please use reqContractDetails() or reqSecDefOptParams() to get the strike prices first.

Thanks for your comment! I am using TWS 10.19, the stable version

Your original code login cannot work. EClient is for requesting while EWrapper is for receiving. You cannot expect the strike data from EWrapper will go back to the EClient function optcontract.strike by itself. Please consider using my below answer suggestion. It will simplify your code structure.

Here is an idea, even better.
Step 1: Use reqContractDetails() or reqSecDefOptParams() to get the strike prices first. Do not directly use reqMktData() to get the live data because you missed right, strike, expiry in your contract details.
Step 2: Use reqMktData() and store the data in an array/dictionary and convert it into a Panads Dataframe.
Note: It seems you can only want to get the 106 Generic Tick Type. You can put mdoff into the function.
Example code:
self.reqMktData(106, contract, "mdoff,106", False, False, [])
Step 3: Use Pandas function to covert the array/dictionary into Pandas Dataframe. Then, filter delta>0.22 / delta<0.18. Then, you do some manipulations on the strike. Doing filter in the IB EWrapper function is complicated.

Thanks a lot! I was able to solve it using tickPrice and tickOptionComputation, however I will definitely have a look at your approach!

Hi Dicer, I tried to understand your comment, but I don't get how you receive the deltas (the ones you are filtering in step 3). Could you please ellaborate a bit more on that? Thanks a lot for your help and patience! KR, Christof
